# Wordpress: HTML sidebar at bottom, instead of right aligned with body

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I added HTML to my `functions.php`. After the

`<?PHP get_sidebar(); ?>`

and before

`<?php get_footer(); ?>`

while the `CSS` is added in my `style.css` Child theme. The result is my box of `HTML` under the main content on my home page instead of being on the right side of the main content. I am hoping someone may be able to help me?

I tried to add my `HTML` and `CSS` but it wouldn't let me post it.

I've spent about 3 hours on this by myself so far. First I tried reformatting a feature provided by the `Minamaze Wordpress` Theme, but I figured I may as well just right my own code as it may be easier to implement.

Comment: Can you post your full code and result?

Comment: I fixed it! Here's how: The real problem was the fact that my front page articles were individually grouped instead of wrapped in a class. I found the index.php file (the copy from my child theme) and surrounded the homepage content in a named div class. I kept my HTML in the same spot as in the OP but in the index.php not functions.php

Once I wrapped them into their own class and wrapped my sidebar boxes into their own class, I used float: left and right respectively in my CSS child theme. I also made their widths percentages to increase usability.

Comment: Daniel, post this as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it! Here's how: The real problem was the fact that my front page articles were individually grouped instead of wrapped in a class. I found the index.php file (the copy from my child theme) and surrounded the homepage content in a named div class. Below is code from my index file. Put a div wrapper class between get_header and the php line below it. Close the div before the get_sidebar.

> get_header(); ?>

```
            <?php while( have_posts() ): the_post(); ?>

                <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class('blog-article'); ?>>

                    <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
                        $column1 = ' two_fifth';
                        $column2 = ' three_fifth last';
                    } else {
                        $column1 = NULL;
                        $column2 = NULL;
                    } ?>

                    <header class="entry-header<?php echo $column1; ?>">
                        <?php thinkup_input_blogimage(); ?>
                    </header>       

                    <div class="entry-content<?php echo $column2; ?>">
                        <?php think_input_blogtitle(); ?>

                        <?php thinkup_input_blogmeta(); ?>

                        <?php thinkup_input_blogtext(); ?>
                    </div>

                <div class="clearboth"></div>
                </article><!-- #post-<?php get_the_ID(); ?> --> 

            <?php endwhile; ?>

            <?php thinkup_input_pagination(); ?>

        <?php else: ?>

            <?php get_template_part( 'no-results', 'archive' ); ?>      

        <?php endif; ?>
```

> ?php get_sidebar(); ?>

Under get_sidebar, you can put in your HTML code for YOUR sidebar that you wish to add.

Once I wrapped them into the php into it's own class and wrapped my sidebar boxes into their own class, I used float: left and right respectively in my CSS child theme, successfully creating a sidebar. I also made their widths percentages to increase usability. You can use this same method in the content-page.php, content-single.php, if you wish to add a side bar to other pages besides just the home screen.